# paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: No hostkey for host xx.xx.xx.xxx found

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko, pysftp

I am trying to use pysftp and gets the same error as many others. That there is no hostkey for host. I have tried many fixes, but none of them seem to work.

When I try to set hostname I get these errors:

```
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys.load('known_hosts')

with pysftp.Connection(host, username, password, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
```

```
/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pysftp/__init__.py:61: UserWarning: Failed to load HostKeys from /home/runner/.ssh/known_hosts.  You will need to explicitly load HostKeys (cnopts.hostkeys.load(filename)) or disableHostKey checking (cnopts.hostkeys = None).
  warnings.warn(wmsg, UserWarning)
```

I have also tried to turn off hostkey, and load locally, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You get that warning, if `known_hosts` does not exist in the default location and you do not specify an alternative location in `CnOpts` constructor.

This should work:

```
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts(knownhosts='known_hosts')
```